# Angular 1.3 $parser validation method not passing test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Recently, we upgraded from Angular 1.2 to 1.3. We still have to support IE8, so bar a few tweaks, everything mostly works.  However, am having a strange issue with a validator failing unit tests, yet still working in real life. Also, it doesn't matter if I move it to $validators, it still doesn't pass. And throwing 1.2 back into Karma passes the test.

It's not a major issue, but can anyone tell me why the below method would fail in 1.3 but not 1.2 (AND actually work correctly)? The specific issue is that validity is set correctly, but the $viewValue is not committed, so $modelValue remains undefined (calling $commitViewValue() and $digest() in my tests does nothing, also,  neither does $el.val(...); $el.trigger(...)).

Test:

```
describe('Future date validation directive', function() {
    var $scope, $form;

    beforeEach(module('myapp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        var $el = angular.element('<form name="form"><input type="date" name="future" ng-model="model.dt" future-date ng-model-options="{ updateOn: \'default\' }" /></form>');

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $scope.model = {
            dt: null
        };

        $compile($el)($scope);
        $form = $scope.form;
    }));

    // This passes
    it('should fail if date is in the past', function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        var yesterday = new Date(now - day);

        $form.future.$setViewValue(yesterday, 'default');
        $scope.$digest();

        expect($scope.model.dt).toBeUndefined();
        expect($form.future.$valid).toBe(false);
    });

    // This fails
    it('should pass if date is in the future', function () {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        var tomorrow = new Date(now + day);

        $form.future.$setViewValue(tomorrow, 'default');
        $scope.$digest();

        expect($scope.model.dt).toEqual(tomorrow);
        expect($form.future.$valid).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .directive('futureDate', [function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, $elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                    var viewTicks = new Date(viewValue).getTime();
                    var currentTicks = new Date().getTime();

                    if (viewTicks > currentTicks) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('futureDate', true);
                        return viewValue;
                    }

                    ctrl.$setValidity('futureDate', false);
                    return;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've worked it out. In Angular 1.3, there is a built in date $parser that validates a date against a string of 'YYYY-MM-DD', as my spec was passing in an actual date object, this was failing. The validation directive still worked in the view, as my datepicker was obviously passing a string. So changing my spec sorted the issue.